nest IF with more than 3 times "and" logic in power BI,
i used below Custom Column in power BI , But there is always an error:','expected. I cannot fine where to put this ","
if [Notification to BET Team] = "No" 
    and not Text.Contains([Master budget grid], "pending") 
    and not Text.Contains([Payment schedule language], "pending") 
    and Text.Contains([Systems Alignment Template Review], "clinical") then
        "Pending SAT submission"
else if [Notification to BET Team] = "No" 
    and not Text.Contains([Master budget grid], "pending") 
    and not Text.Contains([Payment schedule language], "pending") 
    and Text.Contains([Systems Alignment Template Review], "contract") then
        "Pending templates"
else
    null

i tried to put "," in the red coloured Error place, then this error continue to next logic word "els if".

You need to wrap the Text.Contains with not and some ( ) are misplaced :
if [Notification to BET Team] = "No" 
    and not Text.Contains([Master budget grid], "pending") 
    and not Text.Contains([Payment schedule language], "pending") 
    and Text.Contains([Systems Alignment Template Review], "clinical") then
        "Pending SAT submission"
else if [Notification to BET Team] = "No" 
    and not Text.Contains([Master budget grid], "pending") 
    and not Text.Contains([Payment schedule language], "pending") 
    and Text.Contains([Systems Alignment Template Review], "contract") then
        "Pending templates"
else 
    null

